# User value used instead of PHP value in textbox

Tags: php, html, textbox

I have a webpage thats purpose is to edit entries from a database. Its populated using PHP but i need the user to be able to change the value in these and update the database with the new value.

The problem im having is when i POST the data back from the form to the data base, the new information is NOT used, instead the PHP is. How do i fix this?

Each dropdown, text box and text field is populated from the text box using php:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Version</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="forensic_tool_version" placeholder="Version" value="<?php
                $session_name = $_SESSION['first_name']." ".$_SESSION['surname'];
                $sql_query = "SELECT fi_forensic_tool_ver FROM asset_tracker WHERE asset_id = ? LIMIT 1";
                $db_field = "fi_forensic_tool_ver";
                $asset_id = $_GET['assetid'];

                get_db_field($mysqli, $sql_query, $db_field, $asset_id, $session_name);
        ?>"/>
</div>
```

The get_db_field just gets the data and echos it to screen. This all works.

The user will then change one or more fields and click submit, where the following update will occur:

```
                <!-- DATABASE INPUT - Input form elements into database -->
                <?php
                    if(!empty($_GET['requestor']) ){



                        $asset_id = $_GET['assetid'];
                        $add_requestor = $_GET['requestor'];
                        $add_kc_number = $_GET['kc_number'];
                        $add_project_name = $_GET['project_name'];
                        $add_custodian = $_GET['custodian'];
                        $add_business_area = $_GET['business_area'];
                        $add_task = $_GET['task'];
                        $add_utl_reference = $_GET['utl_reference'];
                        $add_purchase_price_value = $_GET['purchase_price_value'];
                        $add_request_date = $_GET['request_date'];
                        $add_return_date = $_GET['return_date'];

                        $add_device_type = $_GET['device_type'];
                        $add_manufacturer = $_GET['manufacturer'];
                        $add_username = $_GET['username'];
                        $add_model = $_GET['model'];
                        $add_pinOrPassword = $_GET['pinOrPassword'];
                        $add_vf_asset_num = $_GET['vf_asset_num'];
                        $add_serial_num = $_GET['serial_num'];
                        $add_imei = $_GET['imei'];

                        $add_forensic_tool = $_GET['forensic_tool'];
                        $add_forensic_tool_version = $_GET['forensic_tool_version'];
                        $add_bitlocker_key = $_GET['bitlocker_key'];
                        $add_image_verified = $_GET['image_verified'];

                        $add_case_notes = $_GET['case_notes'];
                        $add_case_photos = $_GET['case_photos'];

                        if($query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE asset_tracker SET ci_requesting_employee=?, ci_kc=?, ci_project_name=?, ci_custodian=?, ci_business_area=?, ci_task=?, ci_utl_reference=?, ci_purchase_price_value=?, ci_date_requested=?, ci_date_returned=?, di_type=?, di_manufacturer=?, di_model=?, di_username=?, di_password=?, di_vf_asset=?, di_serial=?, di_imei=?, fi_forensic_tool=?, fi_forensic_tool_ver=?, fi_bitlocker_key=?, fi_image_verified=?, cn_notes=?, cn_photos=? WHERE asset_id = ? LIMIT 1")){
                            $query->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssi', $add_requestor, $add_kc_number, $add_project_name, $add_custodian, $add_business_area, $add_task, $add_utl_reference, $add_purchase_price_value, $add_request_date, $add_return_date, $add_device_type, $add_manufacturer, $add_username, $add_model, $add_pinOrPassword, $add_vf_asset_num, $add_serial_num, $add_imei, $add_forensic_tool, $add_forensic_tool_version, $add_bitlocker_key, $add_image_verified, $add_case_notes, $add_case_photos, $asset_id);
                            $query->execute();
                            $query->close();
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Asset updated Successfully');</script>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cannot access database');</script>";
                        }
                    }else{
                        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Post not set');</script>";
                    }
                ?>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown your form. Then print out the contents of the $_GET array to see if it is correctly populated. Otherwise, we do not have a complete picture/question yet.

Comment: Can you add your code for the <form>?
And is there a reason you're using GET and not POST?

Comment: Also note that there is no point in transferring all those $_GET elements to variables if you don't perform any validation or cleaning and simply pass them as parameters.

Comment: The pain in following the prepare and bind_param with it written in a huge line like that ;)

Comment: separate bind_param individually